# Need to add image inside pie chart google api

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I have a requirement where I need to put image inside the pie chart.
I am using the Google chart api.

I have tried this code for drawing pie-chart

```
function drawpiechart(result, id,col1,col2){
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', col1);
    data.addColumn('number', col2);     
    var i=0;
    for (var j in result) {
        i++;
    }
    data.addRows(i);
    i=0;
    for (var j in result) {
        data.setCell(i,0,j);
        data.setCell(i,1,result[j]);
        i++;
    }
    var options = {
          //title: 'My Daily Activities',
           backgroundColor: 'transparent',
           pieSliceBorderColor: 'none',
           pieSliceText: 'label',
           //labels:'value',
           legend: 'none',
           pieHole: 0.2,
           //tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },
           colors: ['#ffffff', '#aee0f1', '#82d4ee', '#62cbe5', '#2ac0e2'],
           pieSliceTextStyle: {color: 'black'},
           chartArea:{left:7,top:7,width:'94%',height:'94%'}
         };
 var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(id));
 chart.draw(data, options);
```

}

[image]

Comment: please add the reason for downvote

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
    console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
  });
```